# WordPress media library won't load

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site in which the media library doesn't load and the ajax spinner keeps spinning. I've switched themes and deactivated all the plugins which no luck. My next step was to change databases which did work. So, there's something in the database that's causing the issue but I'm not sure what to check for specifically.

[image: this is what shows]

Comment: First, you should check for JS errors in the browser's development console (usually Ctrl+Shift+i → Console). If that doesn't reveal anything, try enabling WordPress Debug Log ( https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/ ) and check for errors in there.

Comment: There are no JS errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was a broken database record that was causing the issue. Likely something was interrupted when uploading in the past the caused the record to break.